# How to replace commas inside of brackets with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, brackets

I need to replace "," to "enoComma", but only that located inside of brackets <...>.
I'm trying to do it like this, but it replaces only the first comma inside of the brackets

```
$text = 'asd, asd <asd, asd, adasd> ... ';
preg_replace_callback("/(<.*?),(.*?>)/",
    create_function('$m', 'return $m[1].\'enoComma\'.$m[2];'),
    $text
);
echo $text; // asd, asd <asdenoComma asd, adasd> ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
$text = 'asd, asd <asd, asd, adasd> ... <a,b,c>';

function replace_function($s) {
  return str_replace(",", "enoComma", $s[0]);
}

$text = preg_replace_callback("|<(.*)>|", "replace_function", $text);

echo "$text\n";
```

Output:

```
asd, asd <asdenoComma asdenoComma adasd> ... <aenoCommabenoCommac>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I have made a little touch to reg expression "|(<.*>)|". Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using [preg_replace_callback](http://docs.php.net/preg_replace_callback) I'd let it fetch everything between the brackets and then let the callback replace each comma by enoComma.

```
<?php
$text = 'asd, asd <asd, asd, adasd> asd, asd asd, asd <x, y, z> asd';
$text = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=<)[^<>]+(?=>)/', function($e) {
    return str_replace(',', 'enoComma', $e[0]);
}, $text);
echo $text;
```

prints

```
asd, asd <asdenoComma asdenoComma adasd> asd, asd asd, asd <xenoComma yenoComma z> asd
```

but keep in mind that this won't work with nested brackets like `a,b<c,d<e,f>>`
The example uses a [lambda function](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous) instead of [create_function](http://docs.php.net/create_function).

Comment: Right, nested brackets could have unwanted behavior. The `a,b<c,d<e,f>>` would become `a,b<cenoCommad<eenoCommaf>>`, but even worse would be: `a,b<c,d<e,f>,abc>` => `a,b<cenoCommad<eenoCommaf>,abc>` (note that the comma before abc stays unreplaced!)